# npm run e2e build fails in CI after the timeout of 60 mins without providing the actual error

Tags: angular, typescript, tfs, protractor, azure-pipelines

### My e2e script fails in TFS CI after the build timeout and it doesn't show me the root cause. And it passes randomly in the build. Same script passes in local very well. Please help me out.

```
    **returns LOGS in CI:**

2018-06-15T20:39:06.9176120Z ##[section]Starting: npm run e2e tests
```

## 2018-06-15T20:39:06.9176120Z

```
2018-06-15T20:39:06.9176120Z Task         : npm
2018-06-15T20:39:06.9176120Z Description  : Install and publish npm packages, or run an npm command. Supports npmjs.com and authenticated registries like Package Management.
2018-06-15T20:39:06.9176120Z Version      : 1.0.15
2018-06-15T20:39:06.9176120Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2018-06-15T20:39:06.9176120Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613746)
2018-06-15T20:39:06.9176120Z ==============================================================================
2018-06-15T20:39:07.6364074Z [command]C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" --version"
2018-06-15T20:39:08.7927113Z 5.6.0
2018-06-15T20:39:11.2928469Z [command]C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" config list"
2018-06-15T20:39:12.5585368Z npm info it worked if it ends with ok
2018-06-15T20:39:12.5585368Z ; cli configs
2018-06-15T20:39:12.5585368Z metrics-registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
2018-06-15T20:39:12.5585368Z scope = ""
2018-06-15T20:39:12.5585368Z user-agent = "npm/5.6.0 node/v8.9.4 win32 x64"
2018-06-15T20:39:12.5585368Z 
2018-06-15T20:39:12.5585368Z ; environment configs
2018-06-15T20:39:12.5585368Z loglevel = "verbose"
2018-06-15T20:39:12.5585368Z userconfig = "E:\\Agents\\On-Premise\\vsts-agent-win7-x64-2.124.0\\_work\\27\\npm\\15364.npmrc"
2018-06-15T20:39:12.5585368Z 
2018-06-15T20:39:12.5585368Z ; node bin location = C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
2018-06-15T20:39:12.5585368Z ; cwd = E:\Agents\On-Premise\vsts-agent-win7-x64-2.124.0\_work\27\s
2018-06-15T20:39:12.5585368Z ; HOME = C:\Users\WebSolutionsBldAgent
2018-06-15T20:39:12.5585368Z ; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.
2018-06-15T20:39:12.5585368Z 
2018-06-15T20:39:12.5585368Z npm verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
2018-06-15T20:39:12.5585368Z npm verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
2018-06-15T20:39:12.5585368Z npm verb cli   'prefix',
2018-06-15T20:39:12.5585368Z npm verb cli   '-g' ]
2018-06-15T20:39:12.5585368Z npm info using npm@5.6.0
2018-06-15T20:39:12.5585368Z npm info using node@v8.9.4
2018-06-15T20:39:12.5585368Z npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
2018-06-15T20:39:12.5585368Z npm info ok 
2018-06-15T20:39:12.5585368Z npm info it worked if it ends with ok
2018-06-15T20:39:12.5585368Z npm verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
2018-06-15T20:39:12.5585368Z npm verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
2018-06-15T20:39:12.5585368Z npm verb cli   'config',
2018-06-15T20:39:12.5585368Z npm verb cli   'list' ]
2018-06-15T20:39:12.5585368Z npm info using npm@5.6.0
2018-06-15T20:39:12.5585368Z npm info using node@v8.9.4
2018-06-15T20:39:12.5585368Z npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
2018-06-15T20:39:12.5585368Z npm info ok 
2018-06-15T20:39:12.5741635Z [command]C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" run e2e"
2018-06-15T21:08:39.2025896Z ##[error]The operation was canceled.
2018-06-15T21:08:39.2025896Z ##[section]Async Command Start: Telemetry
2018-06-15T21:08:39.2025896Z ##[section]Async Command End: Telemetry
```

### 2018-06-15T21:08:39.2025896Z ##[section]Finishing: npm run e2e tests

```
**My Package.json**
{
  "name": "consumer-portal",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "ng lint && ng serve -o",
    "serve.dev": "node set-env.js --env=dev && ng lint && ng serve -o",
    "serve.test": "node set-env.js --env=test && ng lint && ng serve -o",
    "serve.prod": "node set-env.js --env=prod && ng lint && ng serve -o",
    "serve.local": "node set-env.js --env=local && ng lint && ng serve -o",
    "serve.staging": "node set-env.js --env=staging && ng lint && ng serve -o",
    "build.test-server": "node set-env.js --env=dev && ng build --stats-json",
    "build.dev": "update-modules.bat && node set-env.js --env=dev && ng build --env=dev --prod=true --aot=false --stats-json",
    "build.test": "node set-env.js --env=test && ng build --env=test --stats-json",
    "build.staging": "node set-env.js --env=staging && ng build --env=staging --stats-json",
    "build.prod": "node set-env.js --env=prod && ng build --env=prod --stats-json",
    "test": "ng lint && ng test",
    "ci.test": "ng lint && ng test --singleRun",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "webdriver-manager update --ignore_ssl && ng lint && ng e2e",
    "bundle-report": "webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json"
  },


  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^0.5.7",
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.10",
    "@schematics/angular": "^0.5.7",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
    "@types/node": "8.0.53",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.5.3",
    "circular-dependency-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.2.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "cssnano": "^3.10.0",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "file-loader": "^0.10.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-reporters": "^2.3.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-ie-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
    "less-loader": "^4.0.5",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.9",
    "postcss-url": "^7.3.0",
    "protractor": "^5.1.2",
    "protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter": "0.0.7",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "ts-node": "~3.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "^2.8.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "webpack": "~3.9.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.11.1",
    "webpack-concat-plugin": "1.4.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "~2.9.5"
  }
}
```

---

**protractor.conf.js**

```
const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');
const Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');
var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');

exports.config = {

  baseurl:'https://consumertst.workpartners.com/login.html',  
  allScriptsTimeout: 60000,
  getPageTimeout: 60000  ,
  ignoreUncaughtExceptions: true,
  specs: [
    './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],

  /*  jvmArgs: ['-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=./IEDriverServer_Win32_3.4.0.exe'],
  seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',

  capabilities: {
      'browserName': 'internet explorer',
      'version': '11',
      'nativeEvents': false,
      'unexpectedAlertBehaviour': 'accept',
      'ignoreProtectedModeSettings': true,
      'disable-popup-blocking': true,
      'enablePersistentHover': true
  },*/
  capabilities: {        
      'browserName': 'chrome',
      'chromeOptions': {'args' : ['incognito']},
  },

  shardTestFiles: false,
    // Maximum number of browser instances that can run in parallel for this
    // set of capabilities. This is only needed if shardTestFiles is true.
    // Default is 1.
  maxInstances: 1,
  directConnect: true,

  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 2500000,
    print: function () { }
  },

  beforeLaunch: () => {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'});
  },

  onPrepare() {
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({
      spec: { 
        displayStacktrace: true }
    }));
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
        savePath: './test/reports/',
        screenshotsFolder: 'images',
        takeScreenshots: true,
        takeScreenshotsOnlyOnFailures: true
    }));
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
      consolidateAll: true,
      savePath: 'testresults',
      filePrefix: 'protractor-test-results',
      modifySuiteName: function (generatedSuiteName, suite) {
        return 'e2e.' + generatedSuiteName; // whichever prefix you wish to use
      }
    }));

    browser.manage().window().maximize();
    browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20000);
  }
};
```

Comment: Since it passes randomly in the build process, have you compared the successful build log with the failed build log to narrow down the issue.

Comment: yes i did, when it passes it provides me [command]C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" run e2e"
2018-06-15T14:05:59.1341895Z > webdriver-manager update --ignore_ssl && ng lint && ng e2e
2018-06-15T14:05:59.1341895Z 
2018-06-15T14:05:59.1341895Z [09:53:37] I/http_utils - ignoring SSL certificate
2018-06-15T14:05:59.1341895Z [09:53:37] I/http_utils - ignoring SSL certificate. But in failed it stops near the cmd run e2e. after that i dont see any logs.

Comment: I know this is old topic. I have similar issue and don't really know what to do with this. Any updates?

Comment: In my case it was missed timeout for wait operation ``browser.wait(EC.urlContains(url))``.  browser.wait(EC.urlContains(url), 30000).catch(...)  displayed the actual test agent issue

Answer (score 0):

I see from your `protractor.conf.js` that you're using `directConnect` to have Protractor launch chrome locally.  This often leads to problems in CI environments because the CI may not support any sort of graphical interface.  Typically in CI environments, people use services like SauceLabs or BrowserStack to host their selenium server, and then use the `sauceUser/sauceKey` or `browserstackUser/browserstackKey` fields to point protractor at that remote selenium server.

That said, there are any number of things that could be going wrong (e.g. `webdriver-manager update` might be failing for some reason), and this is likely the kind of problem which can only really be debugged in person.

In my experience, the best thing to do in this situation is **ask for help from a coworker**.  Find someone who has experience debugging issues in your TFS CI environment, and ask them if they've got time to sit with you and help you through this problem.  If you don't know who has that kind of experience, as your manager or someone on your team if they know anyone, or if they know how where to look for someone.

Comment: how should i use the directconnect in the conf file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was missed timeout for wait operation `browser.wait(EC.urlContains(url))`. `browser.wait(EC.urlContains(url), 30000).catch(...)` displayed the actual test agent issue

```
browser.wait(EC.urlContains(url) // ERROR here. Wait forever
```

Replaced it like:

```
browser.wait(EC.urlContains(url), 30000) // 30 sec
    .catch(async e => {
      console.log('current url is', await browser.getCurrentUrl()) // Display error
      throw e;
    });
```